# How to add object in object? js

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object..

```
var $itemConfig;

//...
//code
//...

$itemConfig =
{
    '$prop1' : $value1,
    '$prop2' : $value2,
};
```

Then I need to add one more object inside loop.

```
for (var o = 0; o < 3; o++)
{
    $itemConfig = {     $oneMoreObj: { [$var1 + o]: $var2 }     };
    // how i can do it? 
    // it should not be replacement.. it should be adding 
}
```

Comment: Assign by key, `$itemConfig['<what you want to call that one more obj>'] = $oneMoreObj;`

Comment: The prop name has to be unique, so you could do `$itemConfig['$prop' + o] = { ... }` in the loop...

Comment: @sameuser try my answer below

Answer (score 0):

If you use a special character on your var you will need to use (`$` is actually accepted in the var name)

```
$itemConfig['$newprop'] = { }; // new object

// without special chars you could do
// itemConfig.newprop = { };
```

```js
var pen = {
  '$prop1': 1,
  '$prop2': 2,
};

var apple = {
  taste: 'awesome',
};

// uuuhg
pen['$apple'] = apple;

console.log(pen);
```

As for adding inside the loop you could do as I suggested

```
for (var o = 0; o < 3; o++)
{
    $itemConfig['$propAdded' + o] = {     $oneMoreObj: { [$var1 + o]: $var2 }     };
    // $propAdded0
    // $propAdded1
    // ... it has to be a unique key name
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem of adding to object inside a loop

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the value assigned to `$itemConfig`, simply don't call an assignment operator on it.

Instead, use dot or bracket notation to assign a new member to the parent object:

```
$itemConfig.$oneMoreObj = { $var1: $var2 };

$itemConfig["$oneMoreObj"] = { $var1: $var2 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your for loop, make use of `Object.assign`. It keeps the old properties of the Object and adds the new ones provided to it.

```
var $itemConfig;

//...
//code
//...

$itemConfig = {
  '$prop1' : '$value1',
  '$prop2' : '$value2'
};

for (var o = 0; o < 3; o++) {
  Object.assign($itemConfig, { ['$newvar' + o]: '$newvalue' + o } );
};
```